# Handle Post request with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some custom code and I am not sure how to catch that Post request.

```
<?php $nonce = wp_create_nonce('nrc_update_certifications_nonce');?>
<?php $link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=nrc_update_certifications&nonce=' . $nonce); ?>
<file-upload
    extensions="jpg,jpeg,png,pdf"
    :accept="accept"
    :multiple="true"
    post-action="<?php echo $link;?>"
    :data="{
        types: accept,
        certifications_ids: certifications_ids,
    }"
    v-model="certifications"
    name="certifications[]"
    @input-filter="inputFilter"
    ref="upload">
    <span class="button">Select files</span>
</file-upload>
```

**In my child theme I have a file update-certifications.php. This file is imported in functions.php**

```
  function nrc_update_certifications() {
    // I don't get here!
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], "nrc_update_certifications_nonce")) {
      exit("No naughty business please");
    }  
    exit ("Works!");
  }
  add_action('wp_ajax_update_certifications', 'nrc_update_certifications');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do that is the following:

```
function nrc_update_certifications() {
    // I don't get here!
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], "nrc_update_certifications_nonce")) {
      exit("No naughty business please");
    }  
    exit ("Works!");
  }
  add_action('wp_ajax_nrc_update_certifications', 'nrc_update_certifications');
```

What changes is that when you do add_action the action starts with "wp_ajax_" and it MUST be followed by what you specify in the action parameter of your call.
Since you build the link like this:

```
<?php $link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=nrc_update_certifications&nonce=' . $nonce); ?>
```

Then the missing part after wp_ajax_ must be "nrc_update_certifications". What you are free to change is the function specified as the second parameter of add_action

Sidenote: if you want that ajax to be available for non-logged user aswell, then you are missing another call to add action which should be:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_nrc_update_certifications', 'nrc_update_certifications' );
```

See the "nopriv" part of the action.
If you want to know more i suggest you to take a look at this: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: I wasn't sure what I did wrong but was just a misspell on wp_ajax_nrc_update_certifications, thank you!